# JSON/PHP/MYSQL login connection error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm new to PHP programming and I'm trying to test out a login page alongside JSON and MySQL. I managed to make most of it functional but I can't seem to find a way to make the query in which I verify the username and password to work.

Please help.

Here's the code:

**login.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#errorLogin').hide();
    $('#formLogin').submit(function(e){
        var username=$('#inputUser').val();
        var password=$('#inputPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'dist/php/connection-login.php',
            data: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            },
            success: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**connection-login.php**:

```
<?php 
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "solucionar_manutencoes_db");

    $lg_user=$_GET['user'];
    $lg_password=$_GET['pass'];

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

    $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_login WHERE lg_user = '$lg_user' AND lg_password = '$lg_password';");    
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($row != 0) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $response["failed"] = 0;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem?What error you get?

Comment: there are multiple dangerous practices here, un-sanatised user inputs, plain text password storage, using get instead of post

Comment: @guradio I'm not sure, but I think the error is in the querry, because I always get the failed response, even though the variables are receiving the inputs

Comment: @smith I know, this is just a test page I'm doing, given I just started studying php

Comment: what does console show when you run.

Comment: `$response` is undefined. `$row` should be an Associative Array `!= 0`.

Comment: @guradio literally only returns {failed: 0}

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP should be more like:

**connect.php** - make sure this is a separate secure page

```
<?php 
function db(){
  return new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'solucionar_manutencoes_db');
}
?>
```

I would change your JavaScript AJAX to a POST request, unless you have a reason for it.

**connection-login.php**

```
<?php
sesson_start(); include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])){
  $db = db(); $r = array();
  $prep = $db->prepare('SELECT `lg_user` FROM login WHERE `lg_user`=? && lg_user=?');
  $prep->bind_param('ss', $_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']); $prep->execute();
  if($prep->num_rows){
    $prep->bind_result($lg_user); $r['user'] = $lg_user;
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $lg_user;
  }
  echo json_encode($r);
}
?
```

Now if your JavaScript AJAX result does not contain the a `e.user` then they are not logged in. Of course, you would probably want to store the original password as a SHA1 or stronger and use AES_ENCRYPTION or better for Personal Information, along with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors in your code.  The first is that you are executing mysqli_fetch_assoc twice: once on the result, and then again on the array the first call returned.  The next is that the $response variable was never declared.  Here is the fixed PHP script:

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "solucionar_manutencoes_db");

$lg_user=$_GET['user'];
$lg_password=$_GET['pass'];

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

$qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_login WHERE lg_user = '$lg_user' AND lg_password = '$lg_password';");    
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);

$response = [];

if (count($results) != 0) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    $response["failed"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

In your JavaScript make sure to use e.preventDefault() inside #formLogin's submit handler to prevent page reload when that form is submitted.